# How to display an attribute of a related model when using collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Have a MTI set up with a Client inheriting from Person. I also have a Project which is in one-to-one relationship with Client model . In my view project/new.html.erb  I would like to create a dropdown menu with client names available for selection.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :XXX, {include_blank: true, :data => {:placeholder => "Select a client"}}, {:class => "chosen-select", :tabindex => "-1", :style => "width:350px;", }) %>
```

The XXX normally is a symbol that signifies the attribute of the direct model ( in this case Client).
How can I display a name attribute which is actually an attribute of a Person class?

**UPDATE**
I added a person_name method to my Client class

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_one :person, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :person_attributes, :pref_hours_of_contact, :pref_method_of_contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person

  def person_name
    person.name
  end
end
```

I have also amended the view:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :person_name, {include_blank: true, :data => {:placeholder => "Select client"}}, {:class => "chosen-select", :tabindex => "-1", :style => "width:350px;", }) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but I believe you can have a method in the Client class that will output the Person attribute. I will assume you want to get a Person name:

Notice what it is said in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) for `collection_select`:

> The :value_method and :text_method parameters are methods to be called
>   on each member of collection

So, if you can send a method to the Client object that will retrieve the Person attribute, you are good to go. This really depends on how you have defined the MTI, but at the end of the day you can always have this in your Client class:

```
def person_name
  # Access your super attribute
end
```

So you could do:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :person_name, {include_blank: true, :data => {:placeholder => "Select a client"}}, {:class => "chosen-select", :tabindex => "-1", :style => "width:350px;", }) %>
```

If you were to use the [act_as](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) gem you could directly use your Person object in the Client `collection_select`.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true, :data => {:placeholder => "Select a client"}}, {:class => "chosen-select", :tabindex => "-1", :style => "width:350px;", }) %>
```